# Gitlab on suse linux

Tags: gitlab, suse

I want to install Gitlab on the suse linux OS.
Could some one please suggest me which OS supported Gitlab installer from the available ones on Gitlab site : Ubuntu, Debian and  Centos can be used to install Gitlab on Suse linux ?

OS details : 
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 4

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Suse is a complete different system. They use a package manager called YaST that won't be compatible with any of the proposed OS on the GitLab website.

Alternatively, you can try installation via Docker (Hopefully your system is 64bits):

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master/docker

Or the hard way, manually:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md

Or even pop an instance somewhere in the cloud but this would involve some costs.

Answer (score 0):

For all other OSs it has packages to install all the required components, but for SUSE there is no package, so you will have to install all the required components like ruby, redis, mysql and other dependent libs on your own.
You may like to try this :
https://gist.github.com/rriemann/5163741
or
https://gist.github.com/jniltinho/5565606

Answer (score 0):

Since I found this answer while looking for the installation on SUSE 12 (SP3), there is one of the currently working options (2021).

1. First, check the [version supported](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/package-information/deprecated_os.html) on the system, (Gitlab 12.1 in case of SUSE 12 SP3, which corresponds to OpenSUSE 42.3)
2. After that, get the proper .rpm [file](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/opensuse/42.3/gitlab-ce-12.1.0-ce.0.sles42.x86_64.rpm) using wget.
3. Install with

   sudo EXTERNAL_URL="http://gitlab.my.domain" rpm -ivh path/to/file/filename

That's it. Some Versions of Omnibus for SUSE are supported directly, but it really depends on the host system version.